# Xubuntu xfce problem

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, xfce, compaq

I have been using Xubuntu on my old laptop and it has been working great.

The other day, I made a lot of updates and after requested login, the XFCE is no longer functioning properly.

I can start applications by choosing them from the list after pushing Ctrl+F3, but I can not see the icons nor the tool bar, status bar or anything else on the screen.

I also get an error message after startup saying that something crashed but when I click on the screen, it just disappears and I can no longer see it.

I tried to repair my installation, but it didn't help either, anyone know how I can clean up the XFCE and get it to work properly?

My laotop is an old Compaq 6715B with 4G memory.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem by re-installing XFCE4, deleting the .config directory from my home and rebooting the computer.

It is now back into normal mode! Still don't know what happened, but for some reason XFCE instalation went bad after latest SW update.